# Phone Number Validation in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have validated my form in such a way that it ain't submitting the data unless the contact field has something else without 11 numeric values. But now I need such phone number validation in Codeigniter that the input field doesn't even let me to type a single character if that is not a number. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phone number validation in php codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838804/phone-number-validation-in-php-codeigniter)

Comment: You can do it with form_validation or if you have a regular expression you can add it by extending the class form_validation

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is jquery plugin which restricts user input to digits only.

This is plugin - http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: If this solved your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Nowadays, the link you provided in your answer is broken. The updated URL maybe what follows: https://github.com/SamWM/jquery-numeric